# Convert list into list of dicts using keys

Tags: python

I am trying to convert two lists into a more complex map.

I have *two lists*, **l1** and **l2**

```
l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
l2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
keys = ["aaa", "bbb"]
result = dict(zip(keys, [l1, l2]))
```

Where *result* is `{'aaa': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'bbb': ['1', '2', '3']}`

But what I want is:

```
[
  {
    "aaa": "a",
    "bbb": "1",
  },
  {
    "aaa": "b",
    "bbb": "2",
  },
  {
    "aaa": "c",
    "bbb": "3",
  },
]
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: why do you think the `dict` constructor would result in a `list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using comprehensions

```py
result = [{k: el[i] for i, k in enumerate(keys)} for el in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A version w/o using `enumerate`:

```
result = [{k:v for k,v in zip(keys,x)} for x in zip(l1,l2)]
```